# Canvas Rect Transform is gray and can't be moved change position. How can I make it to be able to change it's position in the editor?

Tags: unity-game-engine

And the parent of it is just a prefab.

[image: Canvas I want to move]

This is the parent prefab screenshot :

[image: Parent prefab]

Answer (score 1):

Canvas are game objects that usually can't be moved, one reason to move one is because you want it in World Space instead of Screen Space.

Canvas is the container of all of your UI, what you probably want is to move an image, a text, or any other type of UI component, those components must be children of the Canvas and they will be able to move.

You can also have an empty child containing more game objects and that one will be able to move.

Please read more about [Unity's UI](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIToolkits.html) and [Canvas](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/UICanvas.html).